# Activate Windows with OEM product key in BIOS via autounattend.xml

Tags: windows, windows-11, automation, product-key

I'm working with `Windows System Image Manager` to create an autounattend.xml file to automatically install Windows 11 fresh for a set of OEM PCs.

I know each of the OEM PCs I have contain a Windows Product Key embedded in the BIOS. I can retrieve the Product Key when I run `wmic path SoftwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey`.

Using the `Windows System Image Manager`, how can I automatically activate Windows with the OEM product key for the system? Is this even possible?

This is the `Microsoft-Windows-Setup` section for a product key, but I don't want to hardcode a product key in the xml file since each system already has it's own OEM key.

For what it's worth, I'm not working with any volume licensing, so that is out of the question unfortunately.

[image: product key section of the Windows System Image Manager]

Comment: Windows 11 will automatically detect your OEM license key. It’s unnecessary to put it in the unattended xml file. Technically, the license key, isn’t embedded in UEFI.

Comment: You are correct. I ended up entering `XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX` into the product key field in the Windows System Image Manager utility to make the automatic installer happy, and after Windows was installed and connected to the internet, it automatically activated

Comment: You could have also just given it the generic license key and it would have still automatically been activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything :

After some time, Windows will pick up automatically
the Product Key that's embedded in the BIOS and will
activate itself.